# angularjs state onExit callback executed but page transition at the same time

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, transition, state

I have to operate the 'message' view's dom when exit the 'message' view,so I use onExit callback:

```
onExit: ['myservice', function(){
//append a div in 'message' view to another div
}
```

This run normally sometimes,however sometimes I got the error:

```
Error: Dom.get(0) is undefined
```

I think it's caused by the view had been transition to the new view Iclicked so the div can't be find.

Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this if you are using ui-router .
check out [Link for reference](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#wiki-state-change-events)

```
app.run([
        '$rootScope',
        '$state',
        '$location',
        '$stateParams',
        function(
            $rootScope,
            $state,
            $location,
            $stateParams
            ) {
                $rootScope.$state = $state;
                $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

                // here is my event handler
                $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) { 

               });
        }
]);
```

Comment: I try this solution but I got:Unknown provider:$rootScope.what's wrong?

Comment: you need to inject $rootscope

Comment: My code: var app=angular.module('myapp',['ui.router','ui.bootstrap','angular-highlight'];

Comment: no you need to define this code in a controller and inject $rootScope in that controller.

Comment: app.config(['$rootScope',function($rootScope){})

Comment: however I don't have a must-run controller -_-

Comment: I got an error:[ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function,got string

Comment: plz uddate your app,run in the question ?

Comment: just copy yours.And I resolve this by:app.run(function($rootScope){//code}).and this worked. I don't know why.

Comment: ya it was the correct approach u had some minor bug

Comment: bug?my angular?my version is 1.3.15

Comment: that's not the issue  , its same in every version

Comment: Oh. I mean it is a bug of angular?

Comment: However this resolved my another requirement ,it still may get error when I operate my Dom ...

Comment: Oh, I sorry. I think I have found what the problem is. I think I can resolve it.